# Replace text in compressed response from proxy

Tags: nginx, gzip, reverse-proxy

I would like to replace parts of response bodies coming from an upstream HTTP server, which I am reverse proxying with Ngninx.

There the [HttpSubsModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule) with the `sub_filter` directive, but here's the problem

> This module just works with plain text. If the response is compressed, it can't uncompress the response and will ignore this response. This module can be compatible with gzip filter module. But it will not work with proxy compressed response. You can disable the compressed response like this:
>
> `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";`

Hmph.

Are there any alternatives that would allow me to modify proxied content without loosing upstream compression?

Comment: It is a standard configuration to disable upstream compression and to compress in Nginx

Comment: @Dayo, right. My question is whether it is possible to not disable upstream compression, i.e. uncompress, replace, compress.

Comment: It may be possible to involve another webserver/proxy/script between Nginx and your upstream to do this. If you know perl, it should be possible to use the ngx_perl module to intercept, uncompress, replace and compress the data. The ngx_lua module should also be able to handle this. I dont believe you will find an off-the-shelf solution though.

Comment: See this attempt to use ngx_lua: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openresty-en/yVNvA6uhjyA/1ZR7MFZD-RgJ

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue in our case and we used "gunzip" module from ngnix which helped us to uncompress the compressed response and update the response as per the requirement.